# can not extract info from $scope in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a code as follow:

```
function getdata($scope){
 $scope.todos = [
                 {name:"john",data:"1 2 3"},
                 {name:"Marry",data:"6 7 8"},
                 {name:"Edward",data:"2 4 5"}
             ];
 var seri=new Array();

 for(var item in $scope.todos)
     {
        seri.push(
                {
            name: item.name,
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        });
     }
 console.log(seri);
 }
```

Now when I check the console for the name it returns undefined. what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
        function getdata($scope) {
            $scope.todos = [
                     { name: "john", data: "1 2 3" },
                     { name: "Marry", data: "6 7 8" },
                     { name: "Edward", data: "2 4 5" }
            ];
            var seri = new Array();
            angular.forEach($scope.todos, function (item, key) {
                seri.push({
                    name: item.name,
                    data: [1, 0, 4]
                });
            });

            console.log(seri);

            //you can get data from this by using return
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you loop through an array in javascript the item is an integer with the position of the value in the array. You'll need to use this position to get the true item, like this:

```
for (var i in $scope.todos) {
    var item = $scope.todos[i];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function is inside a controller and being called as such you should declare it as

```
$scope.getData = function() {

}
```

And then it should work fine. If the function is NOT to be part of the scope and you are passing the scope in then try receiving the parameter as "scope" and not "$scope" which has a special meaning in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

this is not how you iterate array in javascript (see [materik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25875175/3191896) answer).

you can alternatively use [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) to iterate the `todos` array like this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(item)
{
       seri.push(
       {
           name: item.name,
           data: [1, 0, 4]
       });
});
```